# On appended character keyframes are semi-visible and not saved

Tags: keyframes, dopesheet, append

I have problem with my character, which I append to my file. Keyframes in Dope sheet are semi-visible as you can see in the image. When I change position of any bone of this character, keyframe appears. After closing the file and reopening, new added keyframes are lost. Please help me where is the problem and how can I fix this? Thanks. [image]

Comment: Are you sure that you haven't by mistake linked it. Even from the Append Shortcut, activating "Link" is still possible. Go to your armature settings, and check if you can make it a local user.

Comment: It happend by appending. Today I have made some changes. For example I deleted all Shape keys and created them again. Now I don't have this problem. I think solution is somewhere around Shape keys. I think that this problem could begun as I mistakenly used "V" in one Shape key for separating some vertices. When I will have some time I will test it.

Comment: You can also upload a condensed version of your file to blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com, that way others can experiment with it as well and find an answer quicker.

Answer (score 1):

Click the <kbd>F</kbd> to save the animation in the [Action Editor](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/dope_sheet/action.html). It stands for Fake User. Blender will discard data that does not have a user when you save a file.